# deformation-retracts into a point / contractible : what is the difference?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Okay, I keep reading the definitions over and over, but I don't see the difference between the two ; apparently spaces that deformation retract onto a point are contractible, but the opposite is not necessarily true.

Definition of contractible : A space $X$ is said to be *contractible* if it has the homotopy-type of a point, i.e. there is a map $f : X \to \{p\}$ and a map $g : \{p\} \to X$ such that $fg \simeq \mathbb 1_p$ and $gf \simeq \mathbb 1_X$. Since $fg = \mathbb 1_p$, it suffices to show that there is some point in $X$ such that the identity map $\mathbb 1_X$ is homotopic to a constant map at some point $g(p) \in X$.

Definition of deformation retract onto a point : there exists a map $f : X \times I \to X$ such that $f(x,0) = \mathbb 1_X$ and $f(x,1) = p$ for some fixed point $p \in X$ and $p$ does not depend on $x$.

I believe an homotopy from the identity map to the constant map is precisely a deformation retract, so I don't see the difference.  Or maybe I got the definitions wrong. Does anybody see it? I am quite stuck, since one exercise asks to show that some weird space is contractible but does not deformation retract onto a point.

Comment: Related: [Contractible vs. Deformation retract to a point.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150751/264)

Comment: @Zev : Tried to use the search myself, didn't find it. This is precisely my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a contractible space, the homotopy is allowed to move the point, we don't need to have

$$h(p,t) = p \text{ for all } t \in [0,1].$$

For the (strong<sup>(1)</sup>) deformation retract, $p$ must be kept fixed by the homotopy.

So (strong) deformation-retractability is a stronger condition.

<sup>(1)</sup> Different authors use different terminology. Some call simply deformation retract what others call strong deformation retract, and that seems to be the case if "spaces that deformation retract onto a point are contractible, but the opposite is not necessarily true". If a deformation retract need not keep the retract fixed in the homotopy, the two properties are exactly the same.

Comment: Ooooooh, right. Did not see that difference. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yes, @user8268 beat me to the punch. Different authors have different definitions. I grew up with the definition that allows Patrick to be confused. Daniel's definition is, for me, a strong deformation retraction. So, Patrick, check your book's definition carefully!

Comment: As a simple example, a torus ($S^1\times S^1$) surely cannot deformation retract to a point, but of course is contractible.

Comment: @dezign A torus isn't contractible. $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.