# Contractible and deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

I know there are many questions on this but I ask a proof verification and a clarification. I am trying to prove that given $X$ topological space,

> $X$ is contractible if and only if it is a deformation retract.

The if part is clear to me (it is just a stronger requirement than asking the identity is nullhomotopic)

The only if part: by definition of contractible, $X \sim \{x_0\}$, which holds if and only if the identity map $id_X$ is homotopic to the constant map $\text{const }x_{0}$. Then I take the following retraction: $r:X \rightarrow \{x_0\}$ given by $r = \text{const }x_{0}$.

Denoting $i$ the inclusion of $\{x_0\}$ into $X$, now $r \circ i = id_{\{x_0\}}$ and $i \circ r = \text{const }x_{0} \sim id_X$ by the fact $X$ is contractible.

Nevertheless, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150751/contractible-vs-deformation-retract-to-a-point) people show a space which is contractible but does not deformation retract to any point. What am I missing?

Comment: Hint: Does your construction keep $x_0$ fixed?

Comment: My apologies: I should specify that my definition of deformation retract is that there exists a retraction from $X$ to $x_0$ and $i \circ r \sim id_X$. Hence I think I am not considering the definition of strong deformation retract, right? I guess with this definition the proof should work, correct?

Comment: You seem to be mixing the language. At the top, you want to prove that a space $X$ is contractible if and only if it is the deformation retract of some other space $Y$. But below, you mention a space which is contractible but does not *itself* deformation retract onto a point. That's not a counterexample, since it's talking about a different thing

Comment: I always take $Y$ to be a point of the space $X$, i.e. $Y=\{x_0\}$, with $x_0 \in X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked question considers strong deformation retractions, i.e. deformation retractions which fix points of the subspace at any $t\in[0,1]$.

You are correct that $X$ is contractible if and only if it **weakly** deformation retracts onto some (any) point.

Comment: thank you very much