# Is the homotopy type of an aspherical space determined by its fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

**Question**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be path-connected spaces that admit a contractible universal cover, with $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(Y)$. Is $X$ homotopy equivalent to $Y$?

**Comments**: $X$ and $Y$ are both $K(\pi_1(X),1)$s. In particular, this implies that every homomorphism $\varphi: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y)$ (e.g., the isomorphism) is induced by a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are both CW-complexes, Whitehead's theorem says that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. (In general, by definition, $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence.) So a counterexample requires that at least one of $X$ and $Y$ fails to have homotopy type a CW-complex.

If one removes the requirement that $X$ and $Y$ have contractible universal cover, in particular if one even relaxes it to $X$ and $Y$ have weakly contractible universal cover, the [double comb space](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_comb_space) is a simply-connected counterexample, as it is not contractible. (A proof that it is not contractible can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423640/double-comb-space-is-not-contractible).)

Comment: huh I have a friend called Mike Miller.

Comment: @oxeimon I'm an undergraduate, so probably not me. I was at Penn State in the fall, though, curiously enough.

Comment: Do you only consider spaces, which admit a universal covering?

Comment: @archipelago That was my intent, thanks. I'll edit that in. (I've also removed the word 'aspherical' everywhere but the title because my usage appears to be nonstandard.)

Comment: Did you try $X=S^1$ and $Y$ the pseudo-circle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle ?

Comment: That might work by establishing the Khalimsky line (or Digital line) as its universal cover, since this line is contractible.

Comment: @archipelago It's easy to see that it's a covering space of the pseudocircle; I've been trying to demonstrate a contraction, though haven't gotten one yet.

Comment: From http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2621.pdf follows the contractibility of the Khalimsky line.

Comment: But maybe that's too much overload for you. At least it answers you question.

Comment: @archipelago Yes, it's a great counterexample. (I would have liked an explicit deformation retract, but alas.) Feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As proposed by studiosus in the comments, the standard unit circle and the pseudocircle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle) serve as a counterexample, since their universal covering spaces are the real line and the Khalimsky line, both of them contractible. (The contractibility of the latter follows from http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2621.pdf .)

Comment: Good to know it works: I was trying to prove contractibility of the universal cover by hand and got stuck.

Comment: And this leaves open the question: What happens if we assume in addition that $X, Y$ are, say, metrizable? My guess is that the answer is still negative, but one would play with something like Borsuk's examples of compact locally contractible metrizable spaces not h.e. to CW complexes.  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167954/is-every-paracompact-hausdorff-locally-contractible-space-homotopy-equivalent.