# $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous map. Suppose it induces an isomorphism $f_*:H_*(X) \to H_*(Y)$. Does that imply $f:X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Suppose that $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous map. Suppose it induces an isomorphism $f_*:H_*(X) \to H_*(Y)$. Does that imply $f:X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence?

I think that this is not the case. This is because the following is not True.

> Let $f_*:C_*\to D_*$ be a chain map such that $f_*$ induces an isomorphism in homology. Then $f_*$ is a chain homotopy equivalence,

Can anyone give me a simple example.

Answer (score 6):

No; for example, there are non-contractible spaces that are [acyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_space) (have trivial reduced homology), such as the [Poincare homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar%C3%A9_homology_sphere) minus a point. You can take $X$ to be any such space and $Y$ to be a point.

However, this is true if $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected CW complexes, by a combination of the relative [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) and [Whitehead's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem). This is "Whitehead's theorem for homology."

**Edit:** As for chain complexes, there's a Whitehead's theorem in this setting also: a quasi-isomorphism between two bounded-below complexes of projective modules is a chain homotopy equivalence (see, for example, Proposition 4.1 in [these notes](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~webb/oldteaching/Year12-13/TriangDerivedCatNotes.pdf)). These complexes are roughly the analogues of CW complexes.

Answer (score 6):

In case when $Y=\{*\}$ is a singleton your question can be stated as:

> Suppose $X$ has all homology groups trivial. Is it contractible?

Unfortunately this is false. The double comb space is famously known to have all homotopy, homology and cohomology groups trivial, even though [it is not contractible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423640/double-comb-space-is-not-contractible).

Answer (score 0):

A simple example in chain complexes is the following: consider the infinite complex
$$\cdots  \to \mathbb Z/4\to \mathbb Z/4 \to  \mathbb Z/4\to\cdots$$
where every map is multiplication by $2$. This is acyclic but not contractible over $\mathbb Z/4$. A similar example is afforded by $\mathbb k[t]/(t^2)$ and multiplication by $t$ over this ring.

Comment: However if the chain complex is bounded below it always be contractible over any (commutative) coefficient ring, and when computing homology of spaces this will always be the case.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Aha.